# How to replace a string on sed

Tags: linux, sed

Hi i made a script which is take a data from my db and store it in to a .csv file

the contents of .csv file:

```
1-Mar-12,183991,1017  --- --- more columns are there
2-Mar-12,,,,,,,,,,,,
3-Mar-12,,,,,,,,,,,,
4-Mar-12,,,,,,,,,,,,
5-Mar-12,,,,,,,,,,,,
6-Mar-12,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

when i trying to replace a string depends upon the date it will add all corresponding dates.

for example

i want to replace a string on 2-Mar-12

command is

```
sed "s/$finddate/$finalstring/" dailyrep.csv > DailyReport_$datenow.csv


sed "s/2-Mar-12/$mydata/" origfile > fileto store
```

Output is

```
2-Mar-12,177950,8159,95.62%,6785711
3-Mar-12,,,,,,,,,
4-Mar-12,,,,,,,,,
5-Mar-12,,,,,,,,,
6-Mar-12,,,,,,,,,

11-Mar-12,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
12-Mar-12,177950,8159,95.62%,


21-Mar-12,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
22-Mar-12,177950,8159,95.62%
```

I want to replace only that particular date not all occurrence of that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `sed` command:

```
$ sed "/^$finddate/s/$mydata/$finalstring/" dailyrep.csv
```

It only replace `$mydata` to `$finalstring` on lines which contain `$finddate`.

Comment: Try: sed "/^$finddate/s/$mydata/$finalstring/"

Comment: You can add `^` to the pattern to match the beginning of line.

Comment: Adding `^` the beginning of a regular expression means that the pattern will only match if it's at the *beginning* of the string.  As you saw, sed matched *any* occurrence of '2-Mar-12', including '12-Mar-12', '22-Mar-12', etc.  Adding `^` to the regex means it will only match lines that start with '2-Mar-12'.

Answer (score 1):

`^` in [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) means "beginning of the line". So what you need is to change `"s/2-Mar-12/$mydata/"` to `"s/^2-Mar-12/$mydata/"`. It works not only in sed, of course.